# How to create multiple schools, classes & courses in Moodle

Tags: moodle, multi-tenant, moodle-theme

I want to configure Moodle so I can map a real school structure in the Moodle. I want to add 4 schools and under each I want to add multiple classes. The class in one school might be different in other school. And for each class we may have different subjects & terms (3 terms/semester)

```
-> School
   -> Classes (e.g. Pre Nursery, Nursery 1 ... etc.)
      -> Terms ( currently they have 3 terms in a year)
         -> Subjects (Maths, English etc.)
```

What should be the best way to configure the Moodle. Is there free/paid apps is available that can manage this structure? I have heard about [VMoodle extension](https://docs.moodle.org/38/en/Moodle_Instance_Management) & [IOMOD Extension](https://www.iomad.org/main-features/multi-tenancy/) not sure how effective is this. I am looking for more suggestions if someone has used before.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Moodle has a multi-tenancy option but I don't think its free.

https://docs.moodle.org/311/en/Multi-tenancy

Or you could use this very simple trick which uses the same code but different databases/config.

1. Configure your webserver to server all hosts from a single codebase directory
2. Create a config.php file which includes the individual site config depending on the host which is being served. e.g.

   `<?php`

   `$moodle_host = $SERVER[‘HTTP_HOST’];`

   `require_once(‘/etc/moodles/’.$moodle_host.‘config.php’);`
3. Populate individual Moodle config files with site specific config as you would any other Moodle site

Copied from https://blog.danpoltawski.co.uk/2011/10/multi-tenant-moodle-without-the-2-2-feature/